# Random iteration place get in loop in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have displayed user list in for loop. In between lop randomly I want to display another text. Currently, I have bellowed user-list loop in HTML. every 3 iteration it calls another component.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of userList; let index = index">
       <div *ngIf="index % 3 == 0">
           <app-user-suggestion></app-user-suggestion>
       </div>
</div>
```

Here, My problem is that I want to display that component in a random place in the loop, not every 3 positions. Please suggest to me.

Comment: The best way would be to iterate the loop in typescript/javascript. The best practice is to not write logics in HTML. Write logic functions in back end and use html to display it.This way you will have better control over your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its recommended to do the things in typescript to generate random number..

So, You can use the below method to calculate random number,

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
```

Modified **HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of userList; let index = index">
    <div *ngIf=" (index + 1) % randomNumber === 0 ">
       <app-user-suggestion></app-user-suggestion>
     </div>
</div>
```

Add in **TS:**

```
this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

Here `1` and `10` represents the start and end number respectively to generate random number and i have given 10 users, so you can adjust those numbers according to your need.

Working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9t64c

Comment: Here, one mistake "index % randomNumber === 0" here, we need to add (index+1) bcz only "index" return always first place some value when page referesh.
Thank buddy it's working

Comment: @DipikaPatel, You can change the things according to your need.. Glad to help you..

Answer (score 0):

WE can think that using a Math.random like

```
<!--NOT WORK-->
<div *ngFor="let data of userList; let index = index">
       <div *ngIf="Math.random()>.6">
           <app-user-suggestion></app-user-suggestion>
       </div>
</div>
```

but not work, because Angular, in the .html all the variables are refered to the component, so you need, e.g. write a function in your .html

```
random()
  {
    return Math.random()
  }
```

And write

```
<div *ngFor="let data of userList; let index = index">
       <div *ngIf="random()<.2">
           <app-user-suggestion></app-user-suggestion>
       </div>
</div>
```

**Update** with pagination, we need know how many items there are, so I think that the better aproach is has two variables, userList and userListFiltered

```
  this.userListFiltered=this.userList.map(x=>{
    var obj={...x}
    x.inArray=Math.random()>.2
    return }).filtered(f=>f.inArray)
```

**Update 2** or we can "unsort" the userList

```
this.userList.sort((a,b)=>return Math.random()>.5?1:-1)
```

Then you has all the values unsorted
Then you has an aleatorie array

Comment: with pagination, we need know how many items there are. I updated the answer

Comment: I have 10 records per pagination then in every 10 records in between display user suggestion box? and I have custom pagination

Comment: you can "unsort" the array, a new update in the answer

Comment: Thank you. here, I have concate postlist every next pagination like this.postList = this.postList.concat(postList); So,In this senario this sort solution is working ?